# Will a try/catch around an entire method that contains blocks not catch an exception within a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Look at the code below. If there is an exception in the block `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished){}]`, will the outer try/catch from the `(void)completeAnimationClose` method catch the exception or not?

Or do blocks need their own separate try/catch?

```
- (void)completeAnimationClose
{
    @try
    {
        self.fullImage.hidden = NO;
        [self.fullImageCopy removeFromSuperview];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                         animations:^{self.bgView.alpha = 0.0;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                         animations:^{

                             CGRect rect = [self.tableView convertRect:self.itemImageView.frame toView:nil];

                             self.bgView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, self.itemImageView.frame.size.width, self.itemImageView.frame.size.height);
                             self.fullImage.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, self.itemImageView.frame.size.width, self.itemImageView.frame.size.height);
                             self.btnRemoveImage.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, self.itemImageView.frame.size.width, self.itemImageView.frame.size.height);

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             [self.bgView removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.fullImage removeFromSuperview];
                             [self.btnRemoveImage removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"CRASH");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see how a try/catch would catch an exception in an asynchronous block.  It *might* catch one in a synchronous block -- I still haven't figured out what those are about.

Comment: What exceptions do you expect in that code?

Comment: @rmaddy - I'm seeing crashes from about 0.01% of my users on the line `CGRect rect = [self.tableView convertRect:self.itemImageView.frame toView:nil];` so I am trying to track it down.

Comment: What's the crash error message?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x41770d3b`... not much more info than that. My guess is that the tableView has been released?

Comment: You can't catch that type of crash. The try/catch won't help.

Comment: Even if this did work, you shouldn't be putting `try`/`catch` blocks in your code, anyway. You should eliminate the source of the exception while you're developing the app, rather than putting in run-time handling to hide the exception. Unfortunately, I don't think there's enough here to diagnose the underlying source of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks are executed in a separate context after your `completeAnimationClose` method exits. This puts them in a different scope, making them no longer contained within your `@try {} @catch (..) {}`. This means that any exception thrown within the blocks will not be caught because they will be executing in a different context.

Side note: if you are expecting exceptions within your animation or completion blocks, you might be doing something wrong.

Second side note: exceptions in synchronous blocks would be caught. Example:

```
@try {
  NSArray *array = @[@(1), @(2)];
  void (^test)() = ^{
    [array objectAtIndex:3];
  };
  test();
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
  NSLog(@"Exception gets caught.");
}
```

Comment: The blocks are not executed on a separate thread. All of the posted code is done on the main thread. The blocks may be completed later, but it is still the same thread.

Comment: Yes. That's .. roughly what I meant. Semantics. I'll update it.